# Back-calculating the log-likelihood ratio statistic from a hazard ratio

Tags: survival, cox-model, computational-statistics

I am wondering whether and how can I back-calculate the log-likelihood ratio statistic from a Cox proportional hazard analysis with 1 degree of freedom.

For instance, if I have an hazard ratio (HR) of 0.1327, with standard error of the ln(HR) of 0.0584, what computations should I perform and which would eventually be the log-likelihood ratio statistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the Wald statistic by logHR/SE(logHR). The square of this Wald statistic is typically very close to the likelihood ratio test statistic, since they are asymptotically equivalent.

I don't *think* you can calculate the likelihood ratio statistic given only the estimated log HR and the standard error.

Comment: I tried it a couple of times but I am not convinced. For instance, using Stata -> 'webuse drugtr' -> 'stcox age', I get HR=0.1328, lnHR=-2.0189, SE=0.0584 (thus Wald statistic=34.5703), whereas, according to the output, Log likelihood=-88.00 and LR chi2=23.82. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Indeed, I now recognize we cannot back calculate the LR statistic given only log HR and SE.